# Bootstrap dropdown menu background ending on div

Tags: css, menu, dropdown

So my dropdowns all work fine but I've a main container div with a bg-color and as soon as the multi level dropdown menu goes over it the background doesn't display. The text is fine but the bg stops at the DIV margin.

I've tried using z-index at multiple stages even all the way up the nav div but nothing seems to work.

Has anyone experienced this before? Any ideas?

HTML Sample

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" style="z-index:1;">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-cog"></i> Tools</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level">
        <li class=""><a href="http://aruljohn.com/mac.pl" target="_blank" title="MAC Lookup">MAC Lookup</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.isplocation.net" target="_blank">Locate ISP</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://m.pge.com/#outages" target="_blank">PG&amp;E Power Outages</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
```

Comment: Can you show a code snippet. Like bootply or codepen, something else?

Comment: @rodcunha, put your html and css in [here](http://jsfiddle.net) and then share the link here. Make sure the error is reproduced in the fiddle.

Comment: I've managed to sort this out. Thanks.